# Where do I find archived emails or removed emails to restore them?

Tags: 14.04

I created the mailbox using Plesk Onyx Version 17.8.11 Update #53.

I tried

- locate *.mbox => no results
- locate mbox => no results
- cd /var/spool/postfix =>

  active   defer     etc    incoming  pid        private  trace
  bounce   deferred  flush  lib       plesk      public   usr
  corrupt  dev       hold   maildrop  plesk-pop  saved

Comment: @Nmath I did not archive the emails. I just use Thunderbird on my computer with my 14.04. remote server and removed it in thunderbird.

Comment: @Nmath - Thunderbird saves mail as mbox files. Deleting a mail just hides it but it still exists in the mbox file until you trigger a cleanup of the mbox file where the content is actually removed.

Comment: @Fiximan I did a search for *.mbox on my system, I didn't find any.

Comment: @FabienBiller The files are not called `*mbox` but use the same format. It's just big text files after all. Names match the Thunderbird folder names. (Inbox, Sent , etc)

Answer (score 0):

You said you were using Thunderbird.

Thunderbird keeps its data in your home directory under `~/.thunderbird/<profile_code>.default/Mail` with the profile code being a random set of letters and numbers. You can find `mbox`-type files there.

Comment: I am using Thunderbird on Windows. I did a search for *.mbox on my system, I didn't find any.

Comment: Again: they are not named as such but use the format only - locations are described [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird).

Comment: I found them. Yet they only contain what I already have. There is no backup.